# Browser requesting another page but site shows index page content

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to run a page form the root directory but its shows the index page content on this page. Those pages works fine that came form the database but when i tried to execute any page form root directory (www.domain.com/register.php)is shows the exact page url in browser but shows content of index page, I can't understand it whats going wrong with it.

Here is my .htaccess file code

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule (.*register.php) register.php [L,NC]

## Deny access to extension xml files (uncomment out to activate)
#<Files ~ "\.xml$">
#Order allow,deny
#Deny from all
#Satisfy all
#</Files>
## End of deny access to extension xml files
# Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
########### End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: First thing is to figure out if .htaccess is causing this or not. Rename your .htaccess to something else and then try opening register.php to see what happens.

Comment: Hey Anubhava thanks for your response .. i did all the things but no luck ... if i renamed our .htaccess file site went down ... at last i have connected with hosting providers and they fixed the issue ..:)

Comment: You're welcome, good to know that problem has been resolved.